# How to make a js function run immediately and then on a 10sec interval?

Tags: javascript, ajax

It only runs after 10 seconds. I want it to run when the page loads and then on a 10 seconds interval. Hope someone can help me.

```
function getPrice(){
    $("#ajax").load('somefile.php?sym=<?php echo $yahoosymbol;?> #ajax');
}
getPrice();

setTimeout(getPrice, 10000);
```

UPDATE:

I got it to work after putting the function into a `<body onload="function()">`
none of the other things worked.. I still wonder why?

Comment: Same result.. takes 10sec

Comment: Move the`setTimeout` inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
function getPrice(){
    $("#ajax").load('your code...');
}

getPrice(); //for initial execution 

setInterval(getPrice, 10000); //runs the function on 10sec. interval
```

The **setTimeout()** method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds

whereas **setInterval()** method does the same thing but at specified intervals repeatedly

Comment: That appears to be identical to the code in the question. Did you change anything? Why should that change solve the problem?

Comment: setTimeout(getPrice, 10000); and setInterval(getPrice, 10000); are totally different my friend @Quentin

Comment: That's some more code copy/pasted from the question. You might want to provide an **explanation** instead of just code.

Comment: The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds

Comment: whereas `setInterval()` method does the same thing but at specified intervals repeatedly

Comment: OK, now try hitting the Edit link under your answer and putting that into a sensibly structured form.

Comment: If my code above doesn't work how should this work? and I tried it which gave the same result... starts after 10 sec...